# event generate TCL/TK 8.2

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I would like to make the same thing, that this command below :

```
event generate . <Motion> -warp 1 -x 0 -y 0
```

but for Tk 8.2 , `-warp` (Starts from Tcl Tk 8.3)

Any workaround, idea ?

Comment: 8.2? That's not been supported for decades.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should upgrade ASAP. But if you're stuck at Tk 8.2, on Windows you can download twapi (Tcl Windows API). Make sure you get a compatible version or Tk8.2. Then do:

```
package require twapi

# Move mouse cursor to absolute coordinates 0 0
twapi::move_mouse 0 0

# Move mouse 15 pixels right and 3 pixels up relative to current location:
twapi::move_mouse 15 -3 -relative
```

Comment: I didn't find any version of Twapi which support Tk8.2 ,Thanks anyway